# Stop the cutting off of index.html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure if this question has been asked elsewhere but I can't find anything on it, so here goes..
I am currently hosting a website with which I use a small, simple Javascript function to add effects to certain list items on my navigation bar depending on whether the function is able to find certain matches to text in the address. Here is the function:

```
function NavBar(){
var address = (location.href);
    if(address.search("index")!==(-1)){
    document.getElementById('Nav-Home').firstChild.setAttribute('style', 'color: #cecece');
}
    if(address.search("work")!==(-1)){
    document.getElementById('Nav-Work').firstChild.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #E5E5E5;');
}
    if(address.search("library")!==(-1)){
    document.getElementById('Nav-Tutorial').firstChild.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #E5E5E5;');
}
    if(address.search("contact")!==(-1)){
    document.getElementById('Nav-Contact').firstChild.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #E5E5E5;');
}
    if(address.search("about")!==(-1)){
    document.getElementById('Nav-About').firstChild.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #E5E5E5;');
}}
```

Consequently, my pages are stored in the website directory under each folder name (Work, Tutorial, Contact and About). However, whether I store the index.html file in a separate folder or whatever I can't seem to find away to get the word "index" to appear in the site address (I'm aiming for something like http://site.com/index.html).

Does anyone have any way I can add the index.html to the default home page rather than having it cut off, or perhaps change my function?

Thanks very much

Comment: that sounds more like a web-server configuration issue.

Comment: Seems like a web server issue, rather than a JavaScript one. With JavaScript, you could assume when the address ended with `/` then it was the same as having `index.html`.

Comment: Alex, what web server do you use? The solution would include configuring your web server to load some default page, and then redirecting.

Comment: what server? apache or iis?

Comment: Does the index file _need_ to be called `index.html`?

Comment: I'm not hosting it myself, I'm using freehostingeu.com

Comment: Your link to site.com returns  `Uh oh. You found a page we don't have anymore.*  * or never had`

Comment: That's because it was an example not a real link..................